# Why was this question closed as off topic?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Is [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25042/best-website-for-selling-eu-domain) really off-topic here? It was closed as off topic by John Conde.

The question might be subjective, well actually it is (at least the title, ehich was edited in btw). But if the OP would better write the question I think it would be a good fit here. The question is about the rules of selling an .eu domain which is webmasters related IMHO.

Especially when having [this meta question](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/633/what-can-be-done-to-get-webmasters-more-popular-in-2012) in mind. One of the problems here on webmasters is the fact that there is a real issue of overlap (with SO, SF etc). This question would be a question which doesn't belong on those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Summary:

Post included more than one question and the edit which was suggested and then applied highlighted a question which *is* off-topic for Webmasters - per our [FAQ](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq):

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual
>   problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the
>   usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

SE sites are ideal for getting facts, not opinions: "Where can I sell a .eu domain?" would stand on its own as a community wiki because there is factual content involved, however, "Where is the best place to sell a .eu domain?" is entirely subjective.

I have re-opened the question as requested but I have removed the second question to ensure that the question is in compliance with this site's quality guidelines.

### Timeline:

`2012-01-25 04:55:13Z` - Question posted

`2012-01-25 10:29:04Z` - Revision suggested (which changed title to "Best website for selling .eu domain" and added extraneous tags)

`2012-01-25 13:36:04Z` - Question closed as off-topic

`2012-01-26 00:28:49Z` - Question reopened, extraneous edits rolled back, question edited for compliance with quality guidelines

Answer (score 1):

After reading the linked meta question, I have to wonder the same thing.

This site, webmasters.stackexchange.com, came up as the first choice to ask, since no other stackexchange site seems to be fitting, especially with the keyword "*webmasters*", and anyone who owns a domain is, by definition, a webmaster.

Maybe it's SE politics? I don't really see why my question is offtopic, but I hope that this meta question may shed some light on it.

Comment: I don't believe it has something to do with SE politics. Generally the mods are just doing their best and trying to keep the place clean. Might be just a mistake though or any other reason we'll just have to wait and see.

Comment: @PeeHaa: I agree, it might have been in error.